# Объединение js файлов Laravel через require (is not defined!)

Tags: javascript, laravel

есть отдельный js скрипт модального окна в папке resources/js/modal.js

```
class Modal {
   constructor() {
   }

   show() {
       alert('Готово')
   }

}
```

подключаю его в app.js

```
require('./modal');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const modal = new Modal();

    modal.show()
});
```

и при вызове получаю ошибку Modal is not defined!

Если все прописать в файле app.js, то все работает, а если через require('./modal'), то ошибка...
Не очень хочется делать кашу и писать код в один файл, подскажите что не так (

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто добавить

```
window.Modal = Modal;
```